# What is the difference between 'deemed' & 'deemed to be'?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences?

1. He is the guy whom everyone once deemed a genius.
2. He is the guy whom everyone once deemed to be a genius.

Comment: Very few native speakers would use either ***whom*** or ***deemed*** here. Those are dated / formal terms that don't sit at all well with informal ***guy***. But it makes absolutely no difference to the meaning whether you include ***to be*** or not (no difference to the "tone" either; it's "clunky, but formal" phrasing both ways). More naturally, perhaps, *He's the guy we all thought was a genius once*.

Comment: There's no real difference. Any reason you think there is one?